# Windows Jenkins Git will not clone, only fetch

Tags: git, jenkins, windows-7

Running Jenkins on a Windows 7x64 box.  Have Git Plugin, SSH configured, etc.
Problem is the following, and I cannot for the life of me find other references to the same problem.
The Git plugin is executing against a bare repository (ending with .git), the commandline being generated by Jenkins is always using the "fetch" command as you can see below:
c:\git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@gitrepo-vm/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/ISD/javaTest.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Since this is a bare repository, the fetch command does not work, and it should be using "clone".  I cannot find any configuration, or references to configuration for the Git plugin to use a "clone" and not a "fetch".

Any ideas on why the command line is being generated using the fetch command, and not the clone command, which I see every reference stating it should be this, and works using clone?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by throwing Jenkins on a linux VM.  Once installed and configured, the same exact project configuration worked flawlessly from the linux box.

Answer was don't use windows Jenkins.